# MIDI device (Yamaha electric piano) cuts out after about 15 seconds

Tags: ubuntu-studio, midi

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 on an HP Pavilion with Ubuntu Studio installed, connected via USB to a Yamaha electric piano.  When I start either Rosegarden or `aplaymidi` on a MIDI file, the sound emerges from the piano for about 15 seconds and then cuts out. (The program continues running and still displays progress.) Only a restart will revive the sound.  It doesn't matter whether I try Rosegaden or `aplaymidi` after the cutout. I'm pretty sure neither the piano nor its settings are at fault since everything works correctly in Windows 10 with Yamaha's USB driver (this a dual-boot machine), even when I switch back and forth between Windows and Kubuntu.

How can I track this down?

**Update:** I tried modifying `/etc/default/grub` as suggested in the reply:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="usbcore.autosuspend=-1 quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
```

I then did:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

The behavior did not change -- the sound still quit after about a minute.

Comment: [Report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable USB autosuspend on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140925/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-ubuntu-18-04)