# Disabling USB sleep mode

Tags: usb, suspend

I have installed a full Ubuntu on a USB flash drive. Every time I want to boot into Ubuntu, I just plug the USB drive in and it boots into Ubuntu, and everything works just fine. There is one problem, though. When I suspend the laptop, i.e. when I press the sleep button or when I close the lid, after some time I turn it on again and it gives me external drive errors and some other errors. I think this is due to the USB drive. It somehow automatically turns itself off and since everything is on the drive, I cannot do anything. Whenever this happens, I just force a shutdown.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: There's probably a BIOS setting for the USB ports that keeps power to the USB ports on suspend.

Comment: May be of help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/185274/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-for-a-specific-device

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1161074/48214 looks helpful

Answer (score 3):

You will have to add `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` to the kernel boot parameters.
You can do this by typing `modprobe usbcore autosuspend=-1` into the terminal. Then reboot.

Comment: Here's some extra info: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules -- in my case I want to enable it. You can `modinfo usbcore` to see the current status. `lsmod` also has info.

Comment: (And, the kernel docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt).

Answer (score 0):

I have found only one way to make this work.  The only remote that the power button worked for turning sleep mode on/off was the Ortek VRC-1100.  This is an old Windows media center ir remote that emulates a keyboard (that is probably why it works).  What I did was us the ir learning function for my air mouses power button to learn the power button command for my VRC-1100.  Then I connected the VRC-1100's ir receiver (USB) to the computer.  Then if you put the air mouse in ir mode it can put the computer to sleep and wake it up with no problems. A few years ago I bought about six VRC-1100's.  You need one remote to program the air mouse and a receiver for each computer you want sleep/wake.