# Ch340 keeps disconnecting

Tags: usb, arduino, disconnect

I recently bought a esp32 devkit with ch340 USB-UART bridge.
After plugging it into the USB port of my Ubuntu 22.04 the serial port `/dev/ttyUSB0` repeatedly connects and disconnects.

Also, I have tried this on Windows and Fedora where it worked as expected, so I think it might be a Ubuntu related issue.

`dmesg` output:

```
[ 662.091302] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 117 using xhci_hcd
[ 662.253355] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice=81.33
[ 662.253366] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 662.253370] usb 1-2: Product: USB Serial
[ 662.258186] ch341 1-2:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 662.272620] usb 1-2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 665.739336] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 117
[ 665.739737] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 665.739770] ch341 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
```

`tail -f /var/log/syslog` shows two additional lines:

```
checking bus 1, device 125: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-2"   
bus: 1, device: 125 was not an MTP device
```

I tried:

- disabling autosuspend with `udev` rules as described in [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#USB_autosuspend) (I'm not sure why this doesn't work)
- disabling autosuspend by changing `/sys/devices/*/power/level` to `on` (the file is set back to `auto` after a few seconds)
- updating to the latest kernel
- debugging the driver with kprobe

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? If I won't fix it I'll probably have to change distro, and I don't really have time to do it right now.

Comment: Certainly seems to be the driver.

Comment: `rmmod` will only remove the driver.  If you want to stop that driver from loading you need to blacklist it as well.  Add `blacklist ch341` to the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file to stop the driver from reloading.

Comment: Blacklisting doesn't help, new driver is loaded and used, but the device is still connecting and disconnecting

Comment: Try disabling all power saving features for USB.  I never said that blacklisting will fix your issue, but it will stop the original ch341 driver from reloading is all since you claimed that driver reloaded within a few seconds of removing the module.

Comment: Made an edit on disabling auto suspend

Comment: Not sure if what you followed would work with autosuspend on the USB.  Some are claiming that this one is still working.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1161074/231142  But, I see that you went to Fedora, so this is all moot now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the Ubuntu braille reader was hogging the port. This worked for me.

```
sudo apt remove brltty
```

After that I was able to see the device connect and stay connected. You won't have to run that command again.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work for me. Do you know if there's a way to check if any other program is using the same port?

Comment: If it was brltty the device wouldn't connect at all. I doubt the this would solve the problem.

Comment: This worked for me.
uname: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux