# External drive disconnection after a while

Tags: usb, external-hdd

The external drive is disconnected after a while. I tested in other machine without any relevant issue.

The output of dmesg:

```
[  +0,000172] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Set TR Deq Ptr cmd failed due to incorrect slot or ep state.
[  +0,000090] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[  +0,000021] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 24 ac 4d 20 00 01 00 00
[  +0,000007] I/O error, dev sdd, sector 615271712 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 32 prio class 2
[  +0,000940] device offline error, dev sdd, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 0 prio class 2
[  +0,037334] EXT4-fs (sdd): shut down requested (2)
[  +0,000017] Aborting journal on device sdd-8.
[  +0,000011] bio_check_eod: 77 callbacks suppressed
[  +0,000003] kworker/0:4: attempt to access beyond end of device
              sdd: rw=133121, sector=973340672, nr_sectors = 8 limit=0
[  +0,000007] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 121667584, lost sync page write
[  +0,000006] JBD2: I/O error when updating journal superblock for sdd-8.
[  +0,085438] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  +0,000046] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  +0,275913] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  +0,024769] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=a200, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  +0,000019] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  +0,000004] usb 4-1: Product: External USB 3.0
[  +0,000003] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[  +0,000002] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: <SerialNumber>
[  +0,000931] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  +0,000200] scsi host8: usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[  +1,028029] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  +0,000618] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  +0,001900] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  +0,000370] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[  +0,000007] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  +0,000337] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  +0,080492] sd 8:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
```

The disk is mounted on boot with the following line in fstab:

```
UUID=<UUID> /media/media ext4 nofail,defaults 0 0
```

The output of smartctl -a:

````
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-17-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01UBD... (USB 3.0)
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01UBD100
Serial Number:    <serial_id>
LU WWN Device Id: 0 000000 000000000
Firmware Version: AX001U
User Capacity:    1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Feb 22 20:05:21 2024 EET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 246) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       2969
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5315
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   061   061   000    Old_age   Always       -       15738
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   204   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       900
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       285
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   070   070   000    Old_age   Always       -       302339
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 10/50)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       1903
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       187
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15599         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.```
````

Comment: Check USB power settings in your BIOS.  This system probably shutsdown usb when the usb is inactive

Comment: It seem that there is not such option in the BIOS settings. I've tried this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140925/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-ubuntu-18-04), to disable the USB suspension settings but the issue still remains

Comment: If not USB power management can you try a different cable?